# Unable to use the value of int * in c function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm having some trouble while trying to use the value of a int variable inside a function; a variable that I need to change inside the function, so I passed it as a int * variable, and when calling the function simply passing the address of that variable like functionName(&variable);

But i'm having problems, and I have no idea of why i'm getting error while trying to compile it. (I'm using debian 9)

my function is here:

```
void subvetcont(int * vetor, int tam, int * vetresult, int * tamresult){
  int incmaior=0;
  int fimmaior=0;
  int incaux=incmaior;
  int fimaux=fimmaior;

  *tamresult = 0;

  for(int i=1; i < tam; i++){
      if(vetor[i] == vetor[i-1]+1) fimaux=i;
      else if((fimaux-incaux) > (fimmaior - incmaior)){
          incmaior = incaux;
          fimmaior = fimaux;
          incaux=i;
          fimaux=i;
      }
      else{
        incaux = i;
        fimaux = i;
      }
  }
  for(int i=incmaior, tamresult=0; i <= fimmaior; i++){
      vetresult[(*tamresult)] = vetor[i];
      (*tamresult) = (*tamresult) + 1;
  }
}
```

what I got is

```
ex4.c: In function ‘subvetcont’:
ex4.c:104:14: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   vetresult[(*tamresult)] = vetor[i];
              ^~~~~~~~~~
ex4.c:105:4: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   (*tamresult) = (*tamresult) + 1;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
ex4.c:105:19: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
   (*tamresult) = (*tamresult) + 1;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Am I using pointers wrong?

Comment: can you put code where you have called this function,

Comment: It's a big polluted code, but it's like this

    int main(){
        int vetor[TAMVET], vetres[TAMVET], tamres;
        .
        .
        .
       subvetcont(vetor, TAMVET, vetres, &tamres);
       .
       .
       .
    }

TAMVET its a define

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've declared a new variable `tamresult` in the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = incmaior = 0, tamresult = 0; i < fimmaior; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Within the loop, `tamresult` is that `int` variable, not the `int*` parameter to the function, so you can't indirect through it.

I'm not sure why you put that there. You already assigned `*tamresult = 0;` earlier in the function, there's no need to assign to it in the `for` header. Just remove it.

```
for (int i = incmaior = 0; i < fimmaior; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you!!! 
I'was trying to set the *tamres = 0; not declaring a new one.. 

Just found that it's really bad to init more than one variable within a for header...

Comment: It's fine to initialize multiple variable. But if you put a type before it, you're not just assigning, you're declaring *new* variables with the scope of the loop.

Comment: @MarlonGriebeler <O/T> certainly not a rule, but you may consider moving `*tamresult = 0;` to right above the `for` loop where you erroneously tried to initialize it in. Readers of your code will have less searching to find its current value before you start modifying it in the loop, particularly if more code than you've shown exists between the initialization and the loop. My thinking goes, "Ok, I see `*tamresult` is set to 0 up at the top, now has it changed anywhere else before this loop starts modifying it?"